# SCTP What is the advantage over un ordered message delivery?

Tags: tcp, sctp

It is interesting to read about SCTP protocol. When i compared with TCP, one of the point which is really impressing is un ordered message deliver which is not the case with TCP which always sends the packet ordered. But still, what advantages shall we gain if un-ordered message delivery?. What is the real use case ?

Comment: I think the question is off-topic here. But in short: the advantage is that you can forward the message to the application as soon as it arrived and don't have to wait for retransmission of previously lost messages.

Answer (score 0):

SCTP delivers user's messages sequentially within a stream. If a message that has been sent over stream #A is lost, it will not block any other streams. This solves head of line blocking problem on association level. However the stream A will be blocked until missed message successfully re-transmitted. 
If you application sends some messages that are more important that others (maybe some critical control messages), you might want to deliver them as soon as possible. So, even if a stream (or streams) is blocked due to missed message, you high-priority message still can be delivered to remote end ASAP.